# Pymongo find results to Jinja2

Tags: python, mongodb, jinja2, pymongo

I have a problem that has now consumed me for 2 days solid.
I do a find() in a collection and I get the result below.

My problem is that I cannot seem to access any of the array elements in my jinja2 template.

In my code I have tried:

```
result = list(mycollection.find())
```

as well as:

```
result = dumps(mycollection.find())
```

and then:

```
return render_template("template.html", results = result)
```

My template has the following :

```
{% for x in results %}
 {% for entry in x %}
  <div>{{ entry.departures.status }}</div>
  <div>A break between entries</div>
 {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I get the error that there is no attribute departures.
If i remove the x.status and just put:

```
<div>{{ x }}</div>
```

I get the four entries in list:

```
departures
arrivals
departures
arrivals
```

If I change the template to:
    {{ x[0] }}

returns :

```
d
a
d
a
```

I'm not entirely sure what is in the cursor... Looks like an array of characters ??
Any help appreciated.

find() result:

```
    [
      {
        "departures": [
          {
            "movement": {
              "airport": {
                "icao": "EHAM",
                "iata": "AMS",
                "name": "Amsterdam"
              },
              "scheduledTimeLocal": "2020-05-11 06:05+01:00",
              "scheduledTimeUtc": "2020-05-11 05:05Z",
              "quality": [
                "Basic"
              ]
            },
            "number": "KL 1440",
            "status": "Unknown",
            "codeshareStatus": "IsOperator",
            "isCargo": false,
            "aircraft": {
              "model": "Boeing 737-700"
            },
            "airline": {
              "name": "KLM"
            }
          }
        ],
        "arrivals": [
          {
            "movement": {
              "airport": {
                "icao": "EIDW",
                "iata": "DUB",
                "name": "Dublin"
              },
              "scheduledTimeLocal": "2020-05-11 08:40+01:00",
              "scheduledTimeUtc": "2020-05-11 07:40Z",
              "quality": [
                "Basic"
              ]
            },
            "number": "EI 3240",
            "status": "Unknown",
            "codeshareStatus": "Unknown",
            "isCargo": false,
            "aircraft": {
              "model": "ATR 72"
            },
            "airline": {
              "name": "Aer Lingus"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "departures": [
          {
            "movement": {
              "airport": {
                "icao": "EHAM",
                "iata": "AMS",
                "name": "Amsterdam"
              },
              "scheduledTimeLocal": "2020-05-11 06:05+01:00",
              "scheduledTimeUtc": "2020-05-11 05:05Z",
              "quality": [
                "Basic"
              ]
            },
            "number": "KL 1440",
            "status": "Unknown",
            "codeshareStatus": "IsOperator",
            "isCargo": false,
            "aircraft": {
              "model": "Boeing 737-700"
            },
            "airline": {
              "name": "KLM"
            }
          }
        ],
        "arrivals": [
          {
            "movement": {
              "airport": {
                "icao": "EIDW",
                "iata": "DUB",
                "name": "Dublin"
              },
              "scheduledTimeLocal": "2020-05-11 08:40+01:00",
              "scheduledTimeUtc": "2020-05-11 07:40Z",
              "quality": [
                "Basic"
              ]
            },
            "number": "EI 3240",
            "status": "Unknown",
            "codeshareStatus": "Unknown",
            "isCargo": false,
            "aircraft": {
              "model": "ATR 72"
            },
            "airline": {
              "name": "Aer Lingus"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a jinja2 expert, but I think I managed to get it to work.

```
data_json = """
[
      {
        "departures": [
          {
            "movement": {
              "airport": {
...
...
] """ # data_json is just a copy&paste from the original post. 


import json 
import jinja2

data = json.loads(data_json)
data = {"results":  data}


template_html = """
{% for x in results %}
  {% for deprature in x.departures %}
    Departure   
    <div>{{ deprature.number }}</div>
    <div>{{ deprature.status }}</div>
    <div>A break between entries</div>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
"""

template = jinja2.Template(template_html)
res = template.render(data)
print(res)
```

Some notes about the code above:

- First, there are no 'results' in the original dictionary. Things started to work after adding `data = {"results":  data}`.
- Second, for each entry I'm extracting all the departures, and then the status of each.

Bottom line - seems to be working now ...

Comment: Hi Roy - thanks for this. This worked for of all the departures and then obtaining the status, thanks!

What you did here is also a really good way of trouble shooting. I have been racking my brain, going round in circles the last few days!